# Trying to change state while using a function in React.js

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs

I'm trying to change state of my component while calling of a function.
the function is suppose to take some data and push it in the state

```
  StartChat: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = this.props.FirstName;
    this.setState({ChatBoxMembers:data});
}
```

Calling the above function with and onClick function 
I've check the value gets stored in variable 'data' but the state 'ChatBoxMembers' doesn't change and end up with the error `ChatBoxMembers is not defined` 
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're getting `ChatBoxMembers is not defined` then you probably aren't accessing it correctly. Can you show us an example of you trying to use `ChatBoxMembers`?

Comment: I haven't used it anywhere yet. only setting the state like this `getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            ChatMembers: [],
            ChatBoxMembers:[]
        };`

Comment: do I have to use `bind(this)` here?

Comment: Can you add your constructor code (where you declared your state)?

Comment: Show the full components code.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have declared `ChatBoxMembers` as `[]` but you are assigning linear data to it. Need to have access to code for `ChatBoxMembers is not defined` error.